# Extract character at nth and mth position in string using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a large vector of strings. The strings have no defining features. I want to extract whatever character is at a specific location within the string. In the following example, I would like to extract the 4th character of each of the strings:

```
strings <- c("01234567890", "abcdefg", ".-2dqrst")
```

such as the result would be

```
results <- c("3", "d", "d")
```

After extensive searching I have not been able to come up with a regex that does this, without using some fixed features of the strings, such as locations of special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `substr` in `base R`

```
substr(strings, 4, 4)
#[1] "3" "d" "d"
```

---

Or using `sub`

```
sub("^...(.).*", "\\1", strings)
#[1] "3" "d" "d"
```